# When using AudioKit together with AvAudioPlayer, AvAudioPlayer cannot initialize input

Tags: avaudioplayer, audiokit

I am working on a project where I am using the AudioKit api but the other programmer is using the built-in AvAudioPlayer framework. When running in the simulator everything works fine. However when running on the device AvAudioPlayer crashes when trying to initialize the audio input. When checking the sample rate of the existing audio input the sample rate returns 0.

The problem only occurs if I set AudioKit.output = mixer in my code. if I don't set the audio kit output, then the AvAudioPlayer code runs fine.

Is there an issue where only 1 of these 2 libraries can have access to the input? Is it possible that audio kit is hogging the input so that av audio player cannot access it?

I fully realize that audio kit merely acts as a wrapper around av audio player. however knowing that does not by itself fix the problem.

Comment: AVAudioPlayer is a player and shouldn't have anything to do with the input, so I am not sure what you mean that. AVAudioPlayer is not a framework, but rather a one-off player that Apple provides.  Are you using it for something one of the several AudioKit-based players can't do? There was a thread about someone having problems with AVAudioEngine (which runs at AudioKit's core) and AVAudioPlayer so it might just be that they don't work together well.  Unfortunately Apple deleted the thread as it comes up as a 404 now.